# django python - how to list the progressive numeric value of a list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, listview

I would like to render a list obj with the progressive number as follow:

1. List item 1   #(with id=10)
2. List item 2   #(with id=2)
3. List item 3   #(with id=3)
4. and so on...

I don't want to use the id/pk, since I am ordering the objects alphabetically.

I'm using class based views:

```
class EquipmentType_ListView(ListView):
   model               = EquipmentType
   template_name       = 'equipment/equipment_type.html' 
   context_object_name = 'obj_list' #default = object_list
   ordering            = ['type']
```

with a very simple model:

```
class EquipmentType(models.Model):
   type        = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and the corresponding html:

```
{% extends 'equipment/base.html'%}
{% block content%}
{% for instance in obj_list %}
 <article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ instance.type }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ instance.date_posted}}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is, should I add the code to the views.py or directly to the html file(for cycle)?

I'm not an experienced programmer, but I feel like it should be straight forward. Also it could be very useful to apply generically on all king of list elements rendered out.

I was thinking there should be some "method" on the "for instance in obj_list" where you could print out directly on the html the instance's relative number, or perhaps adding an inner for cycle to do the work. I'm struggling to find anything useful on google searches.

thank you very much for the help.

PS: It is my first post on stackoverflow, I hope I've done everything correctly :)

Carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provides support for this natively: `{{ forloop.counter }}`

```
{% extends 'equipment/base.html'%}
{% block content%}
{% for instance in obj_list %}
 <article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ forloop.counter }}. {{ instance.type }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ instance.date_posted}}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aayush, i knew there was something already built in out there.